# A question on integral over a circles and applying a transformation

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $S_R = \{ (x,y), x^2+y^2 = R \}$ be a circle of radius $R$.

We have a function $f:S_R\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $d V_R$ be the volume form on $S_R$.

Now we consider the integral
$$I = \int_{S_R} f\ d V_R$$.

Now we define $S_1 = \{ (x,y), x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$ and $F: S_R \rightarrow S_1$ such that $$F((x,y)) = (x/R,y/R)$$
Then we can write

$$I = \int_{S_1} f\circ F^{-1} J \ d V_1$$.

where $dV_1$  is the volume form of $S_1$ and J is the Jacobian of the map $F$.

I am confused what exactly is J.

From the definition $F((x,y)) = (x/R,y/R)$ is looks like $J = 1/R^2$.
But since both $S_1$ and $S_R$ are one dimensional manifolds, it should be $1/R$ right?

Can someone please clarify this confusion?

Comment: Yes, $1/R$ is right. You need to calculate in local coordinates, not in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Could you please show how this would be done?